# Ford Escape - Loud Brake Sounds in Reverse

Tags: ford, brakes, cd2

2001 Ford Escape.

I've recently had some work with the transmission done, but in the past 2 weeks or so, whenever I brake while in reverse, it makes a loud grinding sound. However, I've looked through the whole brake system, and I can't find any issues or relations to the transmission that would make it occur only in reverse. Is there anything I should look into with testing, because I really don't want to have to deal with the transmission again unless I'm certain that it's the cause.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the transmission work? And that grinding noise — is it just a noise, or do you also feel vibration somewhere (e.g., in the brake pedal)? Can you tell where the sound comes from?

Comment: Do you get the noise if the car is just coasting backward in neutral? Also, the noise coming from the brakes, not the transmission, right?

Answer (score 2):

Check the e-brake, it could need an adjustment. How is the brake pedal? Is it soft? Is the noise only occurring when pressed hard or when braking soft as well?